# Modify the More button on the Navigation bar of a tab displayed from a UITabBarController's More tab

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have an app with a **UITabBarController** that has more than five tabs.

[image]

When I press the **More** tab, I go to the **moreNavigationController** which is a **UINavigationController**.

[image]

As you can see, I have figured out how to style the **Title**, **Tint**, **Table color**, and the **Edit** button on the **More** screen, as well as the **Configure** screen from pressing the **Edit** button.

What I have not been able to figure out is how to style the back button, titled **More**, when I select an item in the table.

[image]

Each tab has it's own class, **GRWTabSettingsViewController** for example, which inherits from **GRWViewController**, which provides common functionality for all tabs, which then inherits from **UIViewController**.

When on the **Settings** screen (or any other tab), I am trying to edit the **More** back button.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [(UIBarButtonItem *)[(UINavigationItem *)[(UINavigationBar *)[(UINavigationController *)[self navigationController] navigationBar] topItem] leftBarButtonItem] setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]]; 
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
}
```

However, this **navigationController** is clearly the **parent** since these changes get applied to the **More** screen and not the **Settings** screen.

What am I misunderstanding and how would I modify the buttons displayed on the navigation bar of the screen I am viewing?

**=== SOLUTION ===**

[image]

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // use backBarButtonItem not leftBarButtonItem
    //[(UIBarButtonItem *)[(UINavigationItem *)[(UINavigationBar *)[(UINavigationController *)[self navigationController] navigationBar] topItem] leftBarButtonItem] setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    //[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                   target:nil
                                   action:nil];
    [backButton setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
    // these do not work
    //[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    //[backButton setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
}
```

Did take me a while to figure out that I can not format the button through **self**, or format the button after the assignment to **self**.

Comment: Doesn't ANYONE have a thought or comment on this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be customizing `backBarButtonItem` of the previous navigation item, not of the `topItem`.

Comment: [...navigationBar.backItem.leftBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

Comment: The screen [...navigationBar.backItem.leftBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]]; has an effect on is the screen with the More title and the Edit button. Select the More tab, select Settings or About, and select a different tab. When I return to the More tab and use the More button (which is what I'm trying to change), I return to the screen with the More title and the Edit button will change if I use rightBarButtonItem. backItem has no impact on the More button. I want to change the left button on the currently displayed screen. ...

Comment: Using topItem changes the same items as using backItem, it's just a matter of when. topItem will change the button on the More title screen immediately when Settings or About is selected.

Comment: You don't understand me and I don't understand you. You should not be customizing `leftBarButtonItem`, but `backBarButtonItem`.

Comment: Ahhh. Not quite sure how I got confused, but your `backBarButtonItem` comment got me on the right path, although using `topItem` does work for me. Thanks.